# Solution of Equation with summation

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $n= \sum_{i=0}^{10} n_i$  and  $a= \sum_{i=0}^{10} (i \cdot n_i)$ with $n$ and $a$ known, how can I get values of $n_i$ like $n_1$, $n_2$ and so on?

Comment: did you mean $$^n C_i \equiv {n \choose i}$$

Comment: `$a_n$` gives $a_n$.

Comment: There are $11$ variables and $2$ equations!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, no, you can't. For example if you take $n_1=n_3=1$, all rest $0$, then $n=2, a=4$, which can't be distinguished from $n_2=2$.

With specific $n,a$, you can try doing some number theory like modding, then you should be able to gain some information.

Answer (score 0):

Take $n_0=n-a$, $n_1=a$ and all remaining $n_i=0$.